# How to save the data coming from "sudo dpkg -l" in Ubuntu terminal by using python

Tags: python, subprocess

How to save the data coming from "sudo dpkg -l" in Ubuntu terminal by using python, I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work

```
import os
f = open('/tmp/dpgk.txt','w')
f.write(os.system('sudo dpkg -l'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to capture the output of another process:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['sudo', 'dpkg', '-l'])
```

`os.system()` only returns the exit status of another process. The above example presumes that `sudo` is not going to prompt for a password.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick reply, I am trying it :XD

Comment: If you need interaction with the command, try http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect

Comment: how do your code create `'/tmp/dpkg.txt'` file?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It doesn't; the OP already knows how to do that. It was not part of the problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: why do you want to load all the command output into the memory as a string only to write it back to a file immediately? Isn't it simpler (and more efficient in general) just to redirect to a file directly?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It could very well be, but that's not what was being asked. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The non-working code in the question `f.write(os.system('sudo dpkg -l'))` communicates the intent clearly: "write to a file the output of the command".

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yet that version would also read the contents into memory. I agree that redirecting the output straight to the output file is a better idea all along.

Answer (score 1):

To save the output of a command to a file, you could use [`subprocess.check_call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call

with open("/tmp/dpkg.txt", "wb") as file:
    check_call(["sudo", "dpkg", "-l"], stdout=file, stderr=STDOUT)
```

`stderr=STDOUT` is used to redirect the stderr of the command to stdout.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've updated the answer to use the full name.